# Como hago para que mi card ande con el grid de react bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Mi problema es el siguiente, mi card la renderizo mapeandola, osea uso solo una card para que me renderice todas las cards, pero el sistema de grid que tiene react bootstrap, no me deja agregarle 3 columnas para que las cards esten una al lado de la otra ,es decir, en mi caso se renderizan todas las cards una abajo de la otra. Alguna solucion ?

```
  import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import ItemList from './ItemList';


const Item = ({element}) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
              <Card.Img variant="top" src="" />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{element.modelo}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>{element.descripcion}</Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">
                  Añadir al carrito: ${element.precio}
                </Button>
              </Card.Body>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default Item
```

Comment: Estas poniendo cada `Card` en un `<Row>` por separado. Por lo tanto cada una queda debajo de la anterior.

Comment: y que se supone que tendria que hacer en ese caso ?

Comment: Pues no usar un `row` ni `col`. Y verificar cómo usar los CardGroup. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-groups